# Prevent angular 2 ngFor to scroll to top after adding item

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, ngfor

I'm facing an issue with my angular 2 blog app.
I use ngFor to display posts but when I add other posts to the list the window scroll to top.
Can someone help me please?

Heres my code :

```
   export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

      posts : Post[] = [];
      loading : boolean = false;


      constructor(private blogService: BlogService,) { }


      ngOnInit() {
        this.getPosts(this.posts.length);
      }

      getPosts(offset : number){
        this.loading = true;
        this.blogService
            .getPosts(offset,5)
            .then(posts => {
              this.posts = this.posts.concat(posts);this.loading = false;})
            .catch(this.handleError);
      }

      handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
      }


    }
```

and the template :

```
<post *ngFor="let post of posts" [postid]="post.id" [preview]="true"></post>

<button *ngIf="!loading" md-button (click)="getPosts(posts.length)">Plus</button>
<loader *ngIf="loading" [_size]="10"></loader>
```

Comment: Do you have router interaction or url update in someway when it happens?

Comment: Could you add the adding of posts to your questions, since that seems to be the problem here.

Comment: @ jali-ai I have no router interraction.

Comment: @AJT_82 What are you talking about ?

```sh
getPosts(offset : number){
    this.loading = true;
    this.blogService
        .getPosts(offset,5)
        .then(posts => {
          this.posts = this.posts.concat(posts);this.loading = false;})
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: You wrote that when you ADD new posts the window scrolls up, I assume there is a `addPosts`-method somewhere? :)

Comment: I do it for load more post from the backend using an API I do not add post for the moment

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I'm gonna explain the solution for the new visitors.

**Reason**: If you are showing a list of items with *ngFor you should never reinitialize the array ('posts' in this case) also because in case of a long list, it will scroll to the top since for a moment the code will not understand what the array's content is.

**Fix**: To resolve the problem you could add items to the array using array.push() or if it isn't possible, even with the array.map().